# PHP combine 2 arrays (multidimentional) into Array 3 with some calculations

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am sruggeling with the following issue. I have 2 csv files from 2 different suppliers. I want to add the stock of both supplyers to a new total array.

Here is the output of Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ARTNUMBER] => 12345
            [STOCK] =>  3
        )
)
```

Here is the output of Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ARTNUMBER] => 12345
            [STOCK] =>  5
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ARTNUMBER] => 23456
            [STOCK] =>  5
        )
)
```

The new array should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ARTNUMBER] => 12345
            [STOCK] =>  8
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ARTNUMBER] => 23456
            [STOCK] =>  5
        )
)
```

I would like to do 2 things:

- If the ARTNUMBER is in both arrays add them. (array 1 [ARTNUMBER] +
  array 2 [ARTNUMBER]
- If a ARTNUMBER from array 2 does not exist in
  array 1. Add it to the array.

Could someone please help me out how to do this?
(I am looking for the most simple way of doing this)

Comment: You need to check both array in foreach loop and check if both key "ARTNUMBER" match in both array than store it in third array with calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
$array_1[] = array( "ARTNUMBER" => 12345, "STOCK" => 5 );
$array_2[] = array( "ARTNUMBER" => 12345, "STOCK" => 5 );
$array_2[] = array( "ARTNUMBER" => 23456, "STOCK" => 5 );

$data = array();
foreach($array_1 as $key => $value) {
    if(key_exists($value["ARTNUMBER"], $data)) {
        $data[$value["ARTNUMBER"]] += $value["STOCK"];
    }
    else {
        $data[$value["ARTNUMBER"]] = $value["STOCK"];
    }
}
foreach($array_2 as $key => $value) {
    if(key_exists($value["ARTNUMBER"], $data)) {
        $data[$value["ARTNUMBER"]] += $value["STOCK"];
    }
    else {
        $data[$value["ARTNUMBER"]] = $value["STOCK"];
    }
}

$final = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $final[] = array( "ARTNUMBER" => $key, "STOCK" => $value );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi Jabs, thank you for you time! Worked like a charm exept it dint calculate the additional stock. Any way of fixing this?

Comment: Yes Meton, just change if(!key_exists($value["ARTNUMBER"], $data)) to if(key_exists($value["ARTNUMBER"], $data)) remove '!'

Comment: How can i thank you! I spend a lot of time trying to figure this out (not a programmer). Thx a mil!